# nvd3.js lineWithFocusChart range of context graph

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I'm new to nvd3 and d3 in general.

I'm trying to use the lineWithFocusChart example.

I need to modifying it and binding to a realtime source but i want to keep the focus chart starting from an initial value ( in my case 0) and update the context chart with realtime value in a range of 100 values;

my code is:

```
var chart;
var data = 
        [
        { 
          name: 'Acc X',
          key: 'AccX',
          values: [
                    []]
        },
        { 
          name: 'Acc Y',
          key: 'AccY',
          values: [
                   []]        
        },
        { 
          name: 'Acc Z',
          key: 'AccZ',
          values: [
                    []]       
        }
        ];
var dataReset = data;
window.data = data;
function addAccGraph() {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
      chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

      chart.xAxis
          .tickFormat(d3.format(',10f'));


      chart.x2Axis
         .tickFormat(d3.format(',10f'));

      chart.yAxis
          .tickFormat(d3.format(',.3f'));
      chart.y2Axis
          .tickFormat(d3.format(',.3f'));

      //chart.x2Axis.forceX([0]);


      d3.select('#menuOutput svg')
          .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
          .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
      window.chartAcc = chart;
      return chart;
    });



    var x = 2;
    window.runAcc = false;
    setInterval(function(){
        if (!window.runAcc) return;

        var spike = (Math.random() > 0.95) ? 10: 1;
        data[0].values.push({
            x: x,
            y:Math.sin(x) * spike
        });
        data[1].values.push({
            x: x,
            y: Math.cos(x) * spike
        });
        data[2].values.push({
            x: x,
            y:Math.atan(x) * spike
        });

        /*if (data[0].values.length > 10) {
            data[0].values.shift();
        }
        if (data[1].values.length > 10) {
            data[1].values.shift();
        }
        if (data[2].values.length > 10) {
            data[2].values.shift();
        }*/
        x++;

        //chart.brushExtent([0,chart.data("max")]).update();
        //chart.xAxis.scale([0,100]);
        //chart.xAxis.forceX([0]);
        //chart.xAxis.domain([0,100]);
        //d3.select('nv-context').chart.xAxis.scale().domain([0,100]);
        //chart.xAxis.scale().domain([0,100]);

        //chart.xAxis.scale(axisScale);
                         //chart.scale([0,100]);
        //console.log(chart.axis.isOrdinal);
        chart.update();
        //console.log(chart.xAxis);
    }, 100);
}
```

What I obtain is that both chart update and have a 0 - actualValue range.

How can I obtain the "mixed" behaviour if both of them are pointing to the same data variable?

Thanks.

Comment: have you got a fiidle example to explain better?